# How to exclude some paths from (.*) in RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some PHP files

```
index.php
fun.php 
user.php
```

and a few folders such as (`admincp`, `login`, `images` ...)

What I want is:

instead of this : `domain.com/index.php?c=funny&p=2`

this : `domain.com/funny/2`

instead of this : `domain.com/index.php?c=funny`

this : `domain.com/funny`

instead of this : `domain.com/index.php?p=5`

this : `domain.com/5`

instead of this : `domain.com/user.php?p=nice_guy`

this : `domain.com/u/nice_guy`

instead of this : `domain.com/fun.php?p=cool_post`

this : `domain.com/p/cool_post`

Sadly , the only part i was able to achieve was this one:

`domain.com/funny/2`

this is my .htaccess file

```
ewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ fun.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?c=$1&p=$2
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ user.php?u=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^p/([^/]+)$ fun.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)$ user.php?u=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L]
```